# Color in string the row (datagrid wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf

i set color

```
e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Tomato);
```

but how i can set color is string? color code? D7F9C7 for example...

Answer (score 2):

You can set:

```
Brush MyBrush = (Brush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#4CE4FF00");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use static [ColorConverter.ConvertFromString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533.aspx):

```
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#D7F9C7");
```